# .Net wsFederationHttpBinding and SAML2.0

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-security, wsfederationhttpbinding

OK  I have created a SAML Implementation using wsFederationHttpBinding but I do not want to encrypt the soap:Body.

As Specified here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wsfederationhttpsecuritymode.aspx

it says the "Message Security Mode" will,

> By default, the body is encrypted and signed.

How can you turn off the encryption of the Body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found an easier way than creating a custom Binding

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="Service.IService",
ProtectionLevel= System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign)]
```

The Protection Level of the Service can tell the wsFederatedHttpBinding weather or not to Sign and Encrypt or just Sign the message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom Binding.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731827

Comment: Found a much easier way.  See below.